# Chess players who committed murder

Tags: famous-players

Apart from Raymond Weinstein, are there any other examples of chess players of at least Master strength who committed murder?

Comment: The most high profile case was solved by Columbo :) http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0069906/

Comment: Other than the players listed in the comments below, I know of no others.  However, I know many chess pieces that commit murder.  Why if you're a pawn or a Queen you nearly have no chance of survival!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Claude Bloodgood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claude_Bloodgood), the popularizer of the Grob (1. g4), must be far and away the most famous. At one stage his USCF rating was second only to Gata Kamsky! It doesn't get much worse than murdering your own mother.

Comment: Thanks... any less famous examples, maybe?

Comment: PS the inventor of the Grob was, of course, Henry Grob, not Bloodgood.

Comment: @A.N.Other Thanks! I've corrected the answer.

Comment: Bloodgood claims it was only his step-mother.

Comment: Ironically "grob" in Russian means "coffin".

Answer (score 3):

I don't think [Alexander Pichushkin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Pichushkin) played at Master level, but wikipedia implies that he was quite a strong player.

Comment: Even though according to the sources he was very interested in chess, and possibly a strong player, too, nothing suggests that he reached Master strength.